# Ask Ubuntu lens not working in Unity, dash

Tags: unity, launcher

Yesterday I installed Ask Ubuntu lens in Unity, but when I open it dash opens, but I never get any search result.

Dash always stays empty even searching for "Firefox".

Right clicking on the lens in the launcher only gives me the option Ask Ubuntu, nothing more. What can be the problem?

Comment: This is probably this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/askubuntu-lens/+bug/758839 Update and see if it helps, if not, please leave a comment on the bug.

Comment: For 12.10: It looks like disabling the Amazon shopping results disables all lenses that use Online information. I got this working after enabling it the 'online search results' at 'System Settings'>'Privacy'